# How can I upgrade php7.0 to the latest old stable in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, upgrade, php7

Ubuntu 16.04 has php7.0.15.
I would like to upgrade to php7.0.19 which is the latest old stable as of May 2017, or at least to php7.0.18 (it fixes a bug related to PDO and SSL), April version.

I can see here
http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty-updates/php7.0-cli
That 7.0.18 is available for zesty-updates and yakkety-updates, but not for xenial-updates.

I have seen here:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php7.0 that it is included in xenial-proposed

How long will it take to have this version available?

Is there a way to upgrade this package without messing the whole system?

Maybe adding xenial-proposed to the sources list?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found my answer:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed

> To enable the proposed archive for Ubuntu 16.04 and later use the Software & Updates program and ensure that *Pre-released updates (xenial-proposed)* is ticked in the *Developer Options* tab.

Here I can selectively choose packages from proposed.

If someone knows when the proposed goes into updates, that would be a great addition to the answer.